# JQuery fadeIn() when element comes into viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, fadein

I would like to fadeIn() different elements as soon as they come into viewport view, when scrolling down a page.

My code however fades in all DIVs (that have the ".fadethis" class) at once, instead of only when that specific element comes into view:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".fadethis").each(function() {
  var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
  var bottom_of_element = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
  var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
  var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

  if((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
   $(this).fadeIn(10000);
  }

 });
});
```

CSS

```
.fadethis{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you try this? $(".fadethis:visible").each(function() {...});

Comment: Can you also add your html code ?

Comment: your problem probably is that these divs have a style "display: none". During the time they are not shown their top is 0 and the bottom 0 + the height of the div. It's the same for all of them. I've created a pen where the divs fade in as you want them: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/RjJjQM

Answer (score 0):

Import jQuery, [animate.less](https://github.com/codeworksdev/animate.less) and [waypoint](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fromLeft').waypoint(function()
    {
      $(this.element).css('opacity',1);
      $(this.element).addClass("bounceInLeft");
    },
    {offset:'100%'});
    $('.fromRight').waypoint(function()
    {
      $(this.element).css('opacity',1);
      $(this.element).addClass("bounceInRight");
    },{offset:'100%'});
    $('.appear').waypoint(function()
    {
      $(this.element).css('opacity',1);
      $(this.element).addClass("fadeIn");
    },{offset:'100%'});
});
```

And HTML

```
<div class="animated onView fromLeft">
appears from left
</div>
```

[Here](http://www.passaportosalute.it/) you can see an example I made